# Draw text on svg path element with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to modify this [force directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347), and in particular what I'd like to do is to draw text on each graph edge. I tried the following:

```
  // add new links
  path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', function(d) { return d === selected_link; })
    .style('marker-start', function(d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
    .style('marker-end', function(d) { return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : ''; })
    .on('mousedown', function(d) {
      if(d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedown_link = d;
      if(mousedown_link === selected_link) selected_link = null;
      else selected_link = mousedown_link;
      selected_node = null;
      restart();
    })
    .append('svg:text').attr('x', 0).attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id').text(function(d) { console.log(d.id); return d.id; })
```

Only the last line is my modification. I also added an `id` property to the `link` objects so the code I'm working with is not exactly what I've linked to. The log statement is printing as expected but no text or error messages appear. How can I append text right in the middle of each `link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the svg group `<g>`, that will let you append elements inside.

```
var new_paths = path.enter().append('g'),
    links = new_paths.append('svg:path').attr('class', 'link');
```

Be free to add whatever style or behaviour to `links` as you wish.
Then, for the labels, you will append again to the group:

```
var labels = new_paths.append('svg:text').attr('class', 'label');
```

And again you can add whatever you want to `labels`.

When you define the force, you will need to select the links and labels, wich will be something like this:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    labels.attr("transform",function(d){
        return
        "translate("+
            (0.5*(d.source.x+d.target.x))+
        ","+
            (0.5*(d.source.y+d.target.y))+
        ")";
    });
});
```

Here is a demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2oyef30/

### Update

Sorry, I didn't follow your example before. Here is your particular solution.

Change path to be defined as:

```
// handles to link and node element groups
var path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('.path'),
    circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');
```

Inside `function tick() {` you have to select the `.links` or the `.id`

```
path.select('.link').attr('d', function(d) {
```

and manage the new element:

```
path.select('.id').attr("transform",function(d){
    return "translate("+
        (0.5*(d.source.x+d.target.x))+
    ","+
        (0.5*(d.source.y+d.target.y))+
    ")";
});
```

Inside `function restart() {` you have to create a `<g>` element, for example with class `path`, and append the elements into it.

```
// add new links
var newPaths = path.enter().append('svg:g').attr('class','path');

newPaths.append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', function(d) { return d === selected_link; })
    .style('marker-start', function(d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
    .style('marker-end', function(d) { return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : ''; })
    .on('mousedown', function(d) {
        if(d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

        // select link
        mousedown_link = d;
        if(mousedown_link === selected_link) selected_link = null;
        else selected_link = mousedown_link;
        selected_node = null;
        restart();
    });

newPaths.append('svg:text').attr('x', 0).attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id').text(function(d) { return d.id; });
```

The problem with the example definition was that it already selected the `<path>` element making you unable to select the new `<g class="path">`

Comment: that's not quite doing the trick but I'll work from here. Seems like what you're saying is mostly that I need a 'g' element to add a text element and that I need to be in charge of moving these labels once I add them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated the answer with the particular solution, here you have a fiddle with the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5z6cx3p7/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still have to get to know svg way better to use d3 effectively I guess.